# Double operator in R

Tags: r, shiny

As far as i know, we assign double operator so that we can access it globally. But below example is what I am trying

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  HTML('<p id="res">Value</p>'),
  textInput("x", label = "Text"),
  tags$script(
    "
    document.getElementById('x').addEventListener('input', function(){
        document.getElementById('res').textContent= this.value;
    });
    ")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  observe({
    nof <<- 4
  })
  
  browser()
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When I assign <<- to nof, still i am unable to access it. Refer below picture

[image]

Expected output : It was supposed to be 4 right?

Comment: The order of operations is important. In the `server` component, the `observe` blocks (and `reactive` and such) can fire, but only after all of the non-`observe`/`reactive` code fires. means that `nof` is not yet defined when the server-body-only code executes.

Comment: Can you show with an example please :) I did not understand

Comment: Don't call `browser` in the `server` block. Call it inside an `observe` or `reactive` block.

Comment: I understand :) But is it not possible to call it outside?? I need to access this variable globally

Comment: If you want to reference `nof` before the `nof <<- 4` call, you need to define it externally before (and not in) the `observe`

Answer (score 0):

Code *between* observe/reactive blocks execute before any `observe` executes.

```r
shinyApp(
  ui=fluidPage(),
  server=function(input, output, session) {
    message("1")
    observe(message("2"))
    message("3")
  }
)
# Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3237
# 1   # not in observe
# 3   # not in observe
# 2   # in observe
```